# Multiple selections in EXCEL 2010 VBA AutoFilter

Tags: excel, vba, userform, autofilter

First, apologies for my English.
I have this user form, where User needs to select a MONTH from lets say column C using a Toggle buttons. 
**Multiple** months should be possible to be selected at the same time e.g. I want to see results for January + February + May.
I am filtering multiple columns for multiple criteria and at the last column I want to select more than one criteria at a time. 
Lets say I have a column A with all Names, then column B with year, Column C with Month and column D with Product.
What I want to achieve with the user form is, to be able to filter out a single name (I have that done via ComboBox+AutoFilter) Then I want to select(filter) a Year (have done that via ToggleButton+AutoFilter) and then I need to filter multiple entries in the MONTH column (For example I want to see what products Jon Doe bought in year 2015 in the months of January + May + September.
Then I would like to copy all these filtered entries (those visible rows) and copy/paste them into new sheet.

So I have set up these "Month" buttons, I'm able to select ONE month at a time, but not multiple. 
Can you please advise how can I accomplish this ? 
If the toggle buttons are not the good way to do the selection, please advise some other.

I even thought out of not using the AUTO FILTER for the MONTH column, but to use something like:
From the already filtered rows go down and find string "January" or "May" or "September" within the **visible** rows and when you find such row mark it(or select it) and continue searching until first empty row. Then copy all the rows that match the search criteria and copy/paste them to this "new sheet".

But I'm a beginner lama and can't find a way of doing this right. 
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Autofilters allow for multiple selection. Recording a macro will give you the code you need for that.

In your userform, there should be a property of the listbox that allows multiple selection as well.

Should be a relatively straightforward exercise of looping through selected items in the listbox and applying the criteria to the autofilter.

Comment: Sorry, I'm no programmer, I don't know how to figure this out :( I managed to loop through my list of months and display the Month name which is being selected, but I'm unable to make the selection of the months in the Autofilter to work. E.g. I don't know how to tell the code to "If month January is selected, then select month January in the autofilter and move onward with checking the list and if any other month is selected **ADD** this month to the AutoFilter" . :(

Comment: So far the Recording function only allows me to either select one month, or multiple months at a time, but not to **add** months to the ones that are already selected. I'm sorry, doing this over nights after my regular work which is networking and I seem not to have enough brain capacity left :)  Thanks for your tips and sample codes